# Configure SSL on Jasper

Tags: ssl, jasperserver

I want to configure my JasperServer to be accessed over SSL.
I followed the steps based on [apache-ssl-howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/ssl-howto.html)

```
C:\jdk1.5.0_09\bin>keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
Enter keystore password:  changeit
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  teamcakes
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  
Is CN=teamcakes, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown correct?
  [no]:  yes
Enter key password for <tomcat>
    (RETURN if same as keystore password):  
C:\jdk1.5.0_09\bin>
```

I also uncommented the SSL part in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml

```
<Connector
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

But when I open the SSL URL on browser,

[image: password-prompt]

I've tried over couples of username-password:

- tomcat-changeit
- mydesktoplogin-mydesktoppassword

But none of those are correct.
I don't know what username/password should I use?

Anyone have the same problem? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [tomcat-7.0-ssl-howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

I have to change the protocol value
from

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port=8443 ../>
```

to

```
<!-- Define a blocking Java SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           port="8443" .../>
```

And it works!

Comment: To avoid auto configuration you can define which implementation to use by specifying a classname in the protocol attribute of the Connector.